# Flutter cloud messaging: Notification stops after 4 notifications

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Can anyone tell me why my app stops showing notification after about 4 shown notifications.
When I install a new emulator, the notification function works perfectly. but after 4 notifications, it stops. It happens to all the emulators.

Btw, the token is save in the database through a different function. so I just had to fetch it hear. I don't think it's necessary to save it again in the database. Or I'm I wrong?

code:

```
final String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

  /// Initialize the [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin] package.
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  String? mtoken = ' ';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    requestPermission();
    loadFCM();
    listenFCM();
    getToken();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('RIDE_REQUESTS');
  }

  void sendPushMessage(
    String token,
  ) async {
    try {
      await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization':
              'key='*******',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'notification': <String, dynamic>{
              'body': 'You have received a ride request',
              'title': 'RIDE REQUEST'
            },
            'priority': 'high',
            'data': <String, dynamic>{
              'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
              'id': 1,
              'status': 'done'
            },
            "to": token,
          },
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  void getToken() async {
    await adsModel.token;
  }

  void requestPermission() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true);

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
        AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
    } else {}
  }

  void listenFCM() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,

              // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
              //      one that already exists in example app.
              icon: 'launch_background',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  void loadFCM() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
          'high_importance_channel', // id
          'High Importance Notifications', // title
          description: 'A passenger has chosen your ride', // description
          importance: Importance.high,
          enableVibration: true);
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

      /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
      /// heads up notifications.
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }


TextButton(String name = adsModel.uid;
 if (name != '') { DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('ADS')
                        .doc(name)
                        .get();

                    String mtoken = snap['Token'];
                    sendPushMessage(mtoken);
                  })
```

Main.dart:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  // print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider())],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Hitch Ride',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```